# 8 bit adder with 2 CLA

Tags: integrated-circuit, adder, circuit-design, carry-look-ahead

I need to make an 8 bit adder with 2 4-bit look ahead adders.I spent a lot of time reading about it and I think I get the gist of how it works, but I can't seem to get this. I spent a lot of time thinking about it and am stuck.

[image: CLA Chart]

So from the picture, at the end of a 4 bit cla, a generate and propagate is sent out and I assume that I need to somehow connect it to the first C in the second cla(looks like c1 in the pic; basically, first C input). I don't know if that's correct and if it is, I don't know how I should do it. Am I supposed to use some sort of MUX gate? A diagram would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Get a sheet of grid paper, the bigger the better. Draw out the waveform for all possible inputs of a 4-bit cla and then work through it and calculate the outputs. Write the decimal equivalent on there so it makes more sense. A 4-bit cla has a carry in and a carry out signal. Find the signal that you need to add from the first 4-bit cla when it is "overflowing" to the second 4-bit cla.

This is how I did this problem when I needed to solve it.
If you don't like paper then use modelsim.